# Separate ticket connection in Heathrow - can I stay airside?

Tags: transit, short-connections, lhr, connecting-flights, zurich

I have a flight from Zürich to Heathrow scheduled to land in Terminal 2 at 17:55, transferring to a flight to Ireland also out of Terminal 2, scheduled to depart at 21:10.

I will not have any checked bags - should I be able to make this connection in time, and will I have to leave the secure area as a normal arrival, or can I take the connections line, assuming that I have my boarding pass printed?

Answer (score 3):

Because the UK and Ireland are part of a Common Travel Area, you have to do Immigration formalities *in Heathrow*. (There will be no immigration at your Irish destination; your second flight is domestic for immigration purposes.) I can't get the Terminal 2 Map to come up. My recollection is there are clearly-marked separate lines for transferring to UK/Ireland (where you need to get stamped in) vs transferring to Rest of World (stay airside, no checks) vs leaving the airport.

If your first leg is on time, you will make this connection without difficulty. With separate tickets you are, of course, at risk of getting screwed over if the first leg is late.

Comment: So, said immigration controls would simply be a passport check within Terminal 2?

Comment: Also customs on your carry-on.

Comment: Be aware you will also have to clear another security check (with the corresponding 100ml limit on liquids) at LHR -- the UK government basically does not trust security checks done anywhere outside the UK, so anyone who did not originate in a British airport is forced to re-clear security at Heathrow for any connecting flight.